# WinEdt 9.0/language change

Tags: winedt

Is someone here familiar with WinEdt 9.0?
I would like to change the English language to Czech one against which the spelling is correcting. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean? Translating the menus into Czech, or installing a Czech dictionary  for spell checking?

Comment: I mean just switching from English Spelling to installing and checking to Czech one for spelling. I.e. not menus just the red underlinening.

Comment: I've just posted an explanation which is hopefully clear. Other than that, you should update to `WinEdt 10.3`.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to the [Dictionaries page of WinEdt.org](http://www.winedt.org/dict.html) and download the dictionary `cz.zip` and the WinEdt macro `InstallDict`. Follow the instructions thereof and, additionally, define a `CZ` submode, which will be used as a filter for the cz dictionary loading.

Next, from within the `Options Interface`, add this dictionary to the `Dictionaries.ini` configuration file (use what's written for the other already installed dictionaries as a model) and validate.

Comment: How do I make use of this: http://www.winedt.org/macros/winedt/InstallDict.edt ??

Comment: The simplest is to load it in WinEdt, and click on the `Macros` menu, `Execute Current Macro` item.

Comment: What extension should I give it? How do I load it in WinEdt?

Comment: Give an extension to what?

Comment: I have saved http://www.winedt.org/macros/winedt/InstallDict.edt to M.txt. I cannot load it. How do I do that?

Comment: Leave it as it is: `InstallDict.edt`. WinEdt will recognise it as a macro file in its language.

Comment: It writes to me this:  String Parameter Expected IfFileExists('%C\%!2',^^^>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91484/discussion-between-bernard-and-user2925716).